# Formatting a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I get a list of Project Objects by doing this

```
$projects = Project::orderBy('deploymentDate', 'ASC')->get();
```

The output of the above is something like this

```
Collection {#292
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => Project {#293
      #attributes: array:15 [
        "id" => "4"
        "name" => "Something"
        "value" => "234"
        "user_id" => "1"
        "client_id" => "97"
        "contact" => "sdfsd"
      ]
    }
    1 => Project {#294
      #attributes: array:15 [
        "id" => "3"
        "name" => "Something"
        "value" => "6"
        "user_id" => "1"
        "client_id" => "97"
        "contact" => "John Doe"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have removed a lot of the unnecessary data.  So you can see I have two projects.  The problem is, these projects have relationships with other models, so I need to create an array containing all of this data.  So if I do

```
foreach($projects as $project) {
    dd($project->projectType);
}
```

I can see this

```
#attributes: array:6 [
    "id" => "2"
    "additionalInformation" => null
    "project_id" => "4"
]
```

So I have created an array, and I plan on adding the project along with its relationships to this array.  At the moment I am trying this

```
$projectsArray = array();
foreach($projects as $project) {
    $projectsArray[] = array(
        "Project" => json_decode($project, true)
    );

    if($project->projectType) {
        $projectsArray[] = array(
            "Types" => json_decode($project->projectType, true)
        );
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that it outputs the following

```
array:4 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "Project" => array:15 [
       "id" => "4"
        "name" => "Something"
        "value" => "234"
        "user_id" => "1"
        "client_id" => "97"
        "contact" => "sdfsd"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "Types" => array:6 [
       "id" => 2
      "additionalInformation" => null
      "project_id" => "4"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    "Project" => array:15 [
     "id" => "3"
        "name" => "Something"
        "value" => "6"
        "user_id" => "1"
        "client_id" => "97"
        "contact" => "John Doe"
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    "Types" => array:6 [
      "id" => 1
      "additionalInformation" => null
      "project_id" => "3"
    ]
  ]
]
```

So it is adding the data to the array, but not nesting it as relations.  Ideally, I would be after something like this for each project

```
array:1 [
  "Project" => array:2 [
    "Project" => array:15 [
      "id" => 3
      "name" => "Something"
      "value" => "6"
      "user_id" => "1"
      "client_id" => "97"
      "contact" => "John Doe"
    ]
    0 => array:1 [
      "Types" => array:6 [
        "id" => 1
        "additionalInformation" => null
        "project_id" => "3"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "Project" => ...
]
```

How could this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: `dd` is not a builtin. Neither is `Collection`. This looks like laravel - is it specific to the framework? Please either change the code to show how you reproduced the problem with generic php functions, or add a tag for the specific framework you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with how you are building the array. Youa re doing this:

```
$projectsArray = array();
foreach($projects as $project) {
// Add [Project => []] to $projectsArray
    $projectsArray[] = array(
        "Project" => json_decode($project, true)
    );
// $projectsArray now has one element, which is an array

    if($project->projectType) {
// Add [Types => []] to $projectsArray
        $projectsArray[] = array(
            "Types" => json_decode($project->projectType, true)
        );
// $projectsArray now has two array elements, each with a single key
    }
}
```

It sounds like what you want, is to add the Types key/value pair to the array produced by your json_decode, in which case you need to identify that as a distinct thing you can add to, like this:

```
$projectsArray = array();
foreach($projects as $project) {
    $projectarr = array(
        "Project" => json_decode($project, true)
    );

    if($project->projectType) {
        $projectarr["Types"] = json_decode($project->projectType, true);
    }
    $projectsArray[] = $projectarr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I see one problem though, I will no longer be able to do $project->projectType because at this point $project is an Array, not an Object.  Should I call the array something else?

Comment: @kate_hudson yes, I've edited the answer now, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Just create a $project var and array_push it in your array when it's done (primary datas then related datas added).

```
$newProject = array();
$newProject["Project"] = json_decode($project, true);
if($project->projectType) {
    $newProject["Types"] = json_decode($project->projectType, true);
}

array_push($projectsArray, $newProject);
// of $projectArray[] = $newProject;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
$projectsArray = array();
foreach($projects as $project) {
    $projectTmp = json_decode($project, true);
    if($project->projectType) {
        $projectTmp["Types"] = json_decode($project->projectType, true);
    }
    $projectsArray[] = array("Project" => $projectTmp);
}
```

Comment: Could someone explain why this was down voted, thanks